# In Mongolia, what kind of vehicle is a jeep?

Tags: transportation, driving, terminology, mongolia

In Mongolia, what is meant by a jeep?

I assume it is referring to a general type of vehicle, not the [US car brand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeep), as Lonely Planet refers to Russian made jeeps at one point. Is it merely a four wheel drive or sports utility vehicle, or something different?

- What native English speakers think of when they use the generic word "jeep" with a lowercase "j":

[image: generic jeep]

- An example of the American brand "Jeep" with an uppercase "J":

[image: Jeep]

- Russian-made Lada and UAZ, both probably common in Mongolia and could be referred to as jeeps by some people:

[image: Lada]
[image: UAZ]

- Typical Land Rover, Toyota Land Cruiser, and Mercedes 4X4's / 4WD's that some people might call "jeeps":

[image: Land Rover]
[image: Toyota Land Cruiser]
[image: Mercedes Benz four-wheel drive]

(All photos thanks to Wikimedia Commons)

Comment: What are you doing? editing the question to include the meaning of the word "jeep" in English in a question about Mongolia? are you serious? A question can't be about both English language and Mongolia. Voting to close as to broad..

Comment: @HeidelBerGensis who is "you"?

Comment: the one who edited the question to include the off-topic parts..

Comment: @HeidelBerGensis: Not off topic at all. This is a terminology question and we have many users for whom English is not their first language. They may have different ideas of what they think "jeep" means. So before we can know what it could mean in Mongolia we have to be sure we're all on the same page about what it means in English.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's been a while for me since I was in Mongolia, but I'm quite sure that, in this context, 'jeep' still refers to anything that resembles a Jeep.

When I was in Mongolia, the most popular 'jeeps', specifically for touring the country, were Russian made [UAZ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UAZ) 'jeeps'.

They tend to be quite similar to Jeeps. The kind I remember looked quite a bit like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UAZ#/media/File:UAZ-469.jpg).

Answer (score 4):

"Jeep" originally referred to a small US Army scout vehicle built by Willys-Overland during WWII.  More then 640,000 were produced and they were immensely popular with all Allied armies for their sturdiness, simplicity, and reliability.

Since then, "Jeep" has been simultaneously a brand name (of both military and commercial vehicles) that changed hands from Willys-Overland to Kaiser to American Motors to Chrysler and now Fiat, and a generic name for any small or medium-sized 4-wheel-drive on-/off-road vehicle, especially one with a soft top or a removable hard-top, regardless of make or country of origin.

This is more of english.SE question than a travel.SE one, but there you go.  You can read the Wikipedia article [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeep), but really nothing captures the spirit of the Jeep better than the famous [Bill Mauldin cartoon](http://www.awon.org/willie/wj3.JPG).

Comment: This answer would be good if the question was asked in English.SE, but here, it does not answer the question. Jeep has a different meaning in some countries. In the philippines for example it means this local transportation long car, in some arab countries it means a "SUV".. I am sure in Mongolia it means something else, regardless of the origin of the word in English.